# Use Green's Theorem to prove an expression

Tags: calculus

I don't normally like to link images but I can't do the formatting at all. So this is my question

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNcTa.png

And I'm just looking for some guidance, all I've worked out so far is that I need to use Green's Theorem

Comment: Are you sure it is Green's theorem and not Gauss theorem (divergence theorem) you want to use here?

Answer (score 2):

Taking $v=\nabla f$ in Greens Theorem gives:
$$
\int_{\partial C} v \cdot n \; dS=\int_{\partial C} \nabla f \cdot n \; dS=\int_{ C} div(v)\; dx=\int_C \Delta f \; dx
$$
You can check the requirements on the theorem yourself.